Calling Oracle LISTAGG function from a Function
I have written the following Oracle PL/SQL Function that calls the LISTAGG function
create or replace function PK_LIST(SCHEMA_NM IN varchar2, TABLE_NM IN varchar2)
    return varchar2
is
    P_KEY varchar(4000);
begin
        select
            LISTAGG(
                    A.COLUMN_NAME,
                    ', '
                )
                within group (order by A.COLUMN_NAME)
                into P_KEY 
        from
                ALL_TAB_COLUMNS A
                left join ALL_CONS_COLUMNS ACC ON A.COLUMN_NAME = ACC.COLUMN_NAME
                     and A.TABLE_NAME = ACC.TABLE_NAME
                     and A.OWNER = ACC.OWNER
                left join ALL_CONSTRAINTS AC 
                    on AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ACC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                    and AC.OWNER = ACC.OWNER
            where
                AC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
                and A.OWNER = SCHEMA_NM
                and A.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NM;

        return P_KEY;
    end;

select TABLE_NAME, PK_LIST(A.OWNER, A.TABLE_NAME) as MY_LIST
from ALL_TABLES A
where OWNER = 'xxx'-- enter any User/Owner in place of xxx;

When I execute this code I NULL is returned by the function however when I execute the SQL select statement below the code appears to work fine.
declare
    PK_LIST varchar2(4000);
begin
    select
        LISTAGG(
                A.COLUMN_NAME,
                ', '
                )
                within group (order by A.COLUMN_NAME)
                into PK_LIST 
    from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS A
        left join ALL_CONS_COLUMNS ACC ON A.COLUMN_NAME = ACC.COLUMN_NAME
                AND A.TABLE_NAME = ACC.TABLE_NAME
                AND A.OWNER = ACC.OWNER
        left join ALL_CONSTRAINTS AC ON AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ACC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                AND AC.OWNER = ACC.OWNER
        where
            AC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
            and A.OWNER = 'SRSODS'
            and A.TABLE_NAME = 'CONTRACT';

    dbms_output.put_line(PK_LIST);
end;

Why does this function call return the expected result?
Result: I was expecting a comma separated list of Primary Key's for the table as per below:
ACCOUNT_NBR, BRANCH_NBR, COUNTRY_CD

Your code works fiddle. The LEFT JOINs are implicitly converted to INNER JOINs by the where AC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' filter but you want to use INNER JOINs so it (accidentally) works.

I tried creating this function and calling it and I'm getting expected results.
It seems it is returning null when there is no primary key for the table.
enter image description here

Try to embed the image into the answer.
